# Bitbucket: Merge pull request without clicking Approve

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

I already merged a pull request in bitbucket. Can you all explain what is the difference between click Approve and don't click it?
Because I see that the merge commit still appears in git history/log even that I don't click Approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your team has a Premium plan, repository admins can **prevent pull requests that don't have a certain number of approvals** from merging.

Other than that, it is a visual check only that the merge request was reviewed and approved prior to merging.

See: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/pull-requests-and-code-review-223220593.html